# Performance of loading multiple assets for an icon library in React

Tags: reactjs, performance, icons, shared-libraries, assets

I am currently implementing a commmon components library ni React for one of my projects, and I have an `Icon` component that takes an icon name as a prop and displays an SVG icon. The structure of the icon files looks like that :

```js
// names.ts
export type IconName =
  | 'arrow-up'
  | 'arrow-down'
  ...
  | 'zoom-out';
```

```js
// assets.tsx
import { FunctionComponent, SVGProps } from 'react';
import { IconName } from './names';
import { ReactComponent as IconArrowUp } from '../assets/icons/arrow-up.svg';
import { ReactComponent as IconArrowDown } from '../assets/icons/arrow-down.svg';
...
import { ReactComponent as IconZoomOut } from '../assets/icons/zoom-out.svg';

export const IconAssetsMap: {
  [key in IconName]: FunctionComponent<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>
} = {
  'arrow-up': IconArrowUp,
  'arrow-down': IconArrowDown,
  ...
  'zoom-out': IconZoomOut,
};
```

```js
// icon.tsx
export interface IconProps extends SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> {
  icon: IconName;
}

export function Icon ({ icon, ...passThroughProps }: IconProps) {
  const IconAsset = useMemo(() => {
    const asset = IconAssetsMap[icon];
    if (!asset) {
      throw new Error(`Unknown icon name : ${icon}`);
    }
    return asset;
  }, [icon]);
  return <IconAsset {...passThroughProps} />;
};
```

Everything works as expected, and I am able to display an icon by placing the component like that : `<Icon icon='arrow-up' />`. My only concern is that in the `assets.tsx` file, I am loading up all the react component assets in a single object, isn't that a bad pattern performance-wise? Could this affect performances of applications that use this package as a dependency? For instance, if an application only uses *one* icon from that packages, is React or the browser smart enough to not load all of them into memory?

Also, if there is a better approach for this, could you describe it to me?

Thanks a lot for the help